# What is page contentType in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

What is the point of this part of an auto-generated JSP page in IntelliJ IDEA?

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

Because I don't see any loss of functionality if I remove this line. What's its purpose?

Comment: It defines the content type, character set, and language. It doesn't do anything if you remove it because browsers assume an HTML response and a cp1252 or UTF-8 response, and most (all?) JSP pages assume Java. There are other properties available in the page directive as well (e.g., https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/page_directive.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. Why can I not upvote your answer?

Answer (score 0):

A jsp page should have the contentType set to text/html but the webserver may default files to text/html. Same with the charset.

Answer (score -2):

The UTF-8 in the middle is to set the encoding format, otherwise there will be garbled code when the browser opens the page, such as garbled code displayed in Chinese